# Initialize a local versus dynamic DateTime variable

Tags: c#, variables, datetime, initialization

Let's say I initialize a DateTime variable as follows.

Expression 1

```
DateTime foo = DateTime.Now;
```

Question #1 Did I just construct DateTime object without explicitly calling a constructor?

Question #2 Is this possible because the .NET developers set up the DateTime Struct with properties that automatically construct a DateTime Object with a date and time of now?

Next, if I use this syntax

Expression 2

```
DateTime bar = new DateTime();
```

I have dynamically created a DateTime struct.

Question #3 Other than the fact that when I use expression 2 I can specify any date(using a different constructor), when and why would use Expression 1 rather than Expression 2?

Thanks

Rye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes you did.  This is very easy to do with classes, in just the same way that it is with structs.  Consider the following snippet:

   ```
   public class MyDateTime
   {
       public static MyDateTime Now
       {
           get { return new MyDateTime(); }
       }
   }
   ```

   Someone can now write `MyDateTime.Now` and construct an instance of the type without (explicitly) using the constructor.

   Of course, structs *are* actually special, in that I can write:

   ```
   class Foo
   {
       private DateTime date;
       public Foo()
       {
           Console.WriteLine(date);
       }
   }
   ```

   In this class the constructor of `date` is never called, but a date instance actually exists and is constructed, this is because value types are initialized to a default value, which is equal to a bitwise all zeros.  This isn't particularly relevant to the question at hand, but you did ask.

   It's also worth noting that structs are copied when assigned between variables.  Consider the snippet:

   ```
   public static void Foo(DateTime input)
   {
       DateTime copy = input;
   }
   ```

   The assignment is *creating a new `DateTime` instance*.  If this were done with a class it would not, it would only copy the reference to the object, but with value types each assignment, or other operation to copy a variable's value to another variable is *constructing a new object*.
2. There's nothing really special about it from a language perspective.  The `Now` property is overridden to construct an instance representing the current time, that's all.  You can run whatever code you want in a property getter.
3. You'd use `DateTime.Now` if you want to get the current time, rather than a hard coded time.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using the *static* property which returns a new DateTime instance with the current date and time for values. So no you are not explicitly calling a constructor but that does happen somewhere in the execution of the property.
2. No. Its nothing special, just a static property.
3. Nr 1 is for the current date and time, nr 2 is when you want to specify the date and time yourself. So one cannot replace the other, they both have their purpose.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now` is a static property on the `DateTime` class that creates and returns a new instance based on the current local time. You can see the code for what it's doing [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#1cd5dd408a32124f).

*You* didn't explicitly call a constructor, but there's nothing special about it. You called a static property, and *it* instantiated a `DateTime` based on the current time and returned it to you. To be specific it does some checking and then calls an `internal DateTime(long ticks, DateTimeKind kind, Boolean isAmbiguousDst)` constructor as long as the current tick count is inside the range of the DateTime object.

The range of `DateTime` is #01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM# to #12/31/9999 23:59:59 PM#, so the range check is unlikely to ever come into play for `DateTime.Now`.

So use `DateTime.Now` if you want the local time. Use `new DateTime()` (the parameterless constructor) if you want, effectively, `DateTime.MinValue`. Use the various parametered `DateTime` constructors if you want to instantiate a specific time.

Comment: Just because I won't ever be alive outside of those time ranges doesn't mean I'll never want to represent a time outside of that range.  History does go back more than 2,014 years, and some people actually may want to refer to things that happened before that point in time.  Those people cannot use `DateTime` to store their times.

Comment: But that assumes that you only use `DateTime` to represent the current time.  That's a false assumption.

Comment: `new DateTime()` *doesn't* represent the current time.  It represents `DateTime.MinValue`.  Once again, you're saying that if you only ever use `DateTime` to represent the current time the range is way more than needed.  That's true, but people us `DateTime` to represent all sorts of dates, not just the current one, so given that people try to represent all sorts of dates, it may or may not actually have a range suitable for any given person.  You specifically mention it in the constructor.  People using the constructor almost never are trying to create the current time.